# Apex Chart Toolbar not showing all tools

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[Only download tool visible not all the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Q3O.png)

only this download icon is there in toolbar I want all the option in toolbar Please help how can I do this

```
chart: { height: 350, type: "bar", toolbar: { show: true, tools: { download: true, selection: true, zoom: true, zoomin: true, zoomout: true, pan: true, reset: true }, }, zoom: { enabled: true } },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add some more context to your question, e.g. what type of application this is for?

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding this in   xaxis: {tickPlacement: 'on',}

Answer (score 13):

I have resolved this issue by adding this in xaxis: `{tickPlacement: 'on',}`

Comment: Note, this is obviously based on the comment by @ManishaGupta . The deletion of "Thanks" (i.e. the little implicit credit giving part) I take unto me. I did because I think turning it into an answer is appropriate. I hope this OK. Thanks Manisha. Consider making an answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
toolbar: {
    tools: {
        download: true,
        selection: true,
        zoom: true,
        zoomin: true,
        zoomout: true,
        pan: true,
        reset: true | '<img src="/static/icons/reset.png" width="20">',
        customIcons: []
    }
}
```